# Why the accuracy of the neural network stops increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to solve the Titanic competition on Kaggle. But the modelaccuracy isn't going beyond 80%.
I tried to change a number of hidden nodes, a number of epochs, also tried to apply batch normalization, dropout, changing the weights initializations, but there's the same 80%. What am I doing wrong? 
This is my code below:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(5,), kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(), activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_scores = model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=200, batch_size=64, verbose=2)
```

And here's on the picture accuracy in some last epochs:[model accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JzIk.png)

How can I improve it?

Comment: What makes you think you are doing anything wrong? Explaining why a network gives some specific performance is not really a programming issue

Comment: Consider a different model architecture. Gather / generate more data. Decrease the learning rate. Check out [fastai](https://course.fast.ai/) for inspiration.

Comment: The code seems to be fine. Please consider posting the question in a machine learning forum.

Comment: Are your labels one-hot encoded?

Comment: @desertnaut yes

Answer (score 0):

You can try normalising the data, Generally while implementing Neural Networks we don't need to normalise our data (if the network is deep) but since here we are only working with 3 layers only I guess normalising the data might help.

I would suggest to split your training data again into training and validation set and use K-fold cross validation ( I am not sure about this one!! I too am new in this field).

But in general I have seen if the accuracy is constant then the best approach is to alter the training data ( I mean normalise it or try imputing NaN values with the mean (rather than setting the to 0)).